# Magento 1.9 - Amasty FPC: How do I ignore a block permanently

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

We're using Amasty FPC and we're running into a wall where we have two blocks that we want to never be cached.

However, none of the code examples provided by Amasty, their "manual", or any online help I've googled provide a solution that explains how to do this.

Is there anyone with experience with this extension that can shed some light?

The relevant code, as I understand it.

**amfpc.xml**

```
<nav_application_selector_mobile> <!-- the block name -->
   <routes>
     <catalogsearch>catalogsearch/result/*</catalogsearch>
     <shop>shop/*</shop>
   </routes>
</nav_application_selector_mobile>

<app_selector parent="header" />
```

**header.phtml**

```
<amfpc name="app_selector"> <!-- the custom block reference for amfpc -->
    <div id="top-menu-search-by-vehicle" class="menu-opt">
       ...
    </div>
</amfpc>
```

This supposedly is supposed to clear the block's cache on certain routes, as well as set a punch hole around the other block so that it never gets cached.

After hours of trying to get this to work, I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there and thanks for your question. Each block should be reviewed individually, and thus we can't help you from here without seeing the details. Please do create a ticket at our support center, and we will be happy to help you with this one. Cheers!